# Python 3.7 : ValueError on both GridSearchCV and RandomizedSearch CV -Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').-

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science, grid-search, hyperparameters

I have been trying to tune my XGBoost Regressor but I keep getting

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for
>   dtype('float32').

When I try models with some of the parameters I'm trying, the model is working but whenever I put those into GridSearchCv or RandomizedSearchCV it is not working.

One funny thing is my input dtypes are "float64", but the error I'm getting 'float32'. I assume these functions convert during their work.

Please find my code below;

```
xgbm = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective='reg:squarederror')
xgbm.fit(Xn_train, yn_train)

y_pred_xgb = xgbm.predict(Xn_test)
y_pred_xgb_t = xgbm.predict(Xn_train)

print('Train MSE: {:.3f}'.format(mean_squared_error(yn_train, y_pred_xgb_t)))
print('Test MSE: {:.3f}'.format(mean_squared_error(yn_test, y_pred_xgb)))

plt.scatter(yn_test, y_pred_xgb)
```

[Actual vs Predicted Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXsav.png)

```
max_depth = [3, 5, 7]
learning_rate = [0.1, 1, 10]
n_estimators = [100, 200]
colsample_bytree = [0.8, 1]

params = {'max_depth':max_depth, 'learning_rate':learning_rate, 'n_estimators':n_estimators, 
          'colsample_bytree':colsample_bytree}

gridcv = RandomizedSearchCV(xgbm,param_distributions=params, n_iter=5, 
                            scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', return_train_score=True, verbose=1)

gridcv.fit(Xn_train, yn_train)
```

The error message I'm getting is:

```
Fitting 3 folds for each of 5 candidates, totalling 15 fits
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-dffd2fffe03a> in <module>
----> 1 gridcv.fit(Xn_train, yn_train)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    686                 return results
    687 
--> 688             self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    689 
    690         # For multi-metric evaluation, store the best_index_, best_params_ and

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
   1467         evaluate_candidates(ParameterSampler(
   1468             self.param_distributions, self.n_iter,
-> 1469             random_state=self.random_state))

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in evaluate_candidates(candidate_params)
    665                                for parameters, (train, test)
    666                                in product(candidate_params,
--> 667                                           cv.split(X, y, groups)))
    668 
    669                 if len(out) < 1:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    922                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
    923 
--> 924             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    925                 pass
    926 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    757                 return False
    758             else:
--> 759                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    760                 return True
    761 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    714         with self._lock:
    715             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 716             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    717             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    718             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    180     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    181         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 182         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    183         if callback:
    184             callback(result)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    547         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    548         # arguments in memory
--> 549         self.results = batch()
    550 
    551     def get(self):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self)
    223         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    224             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 225                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    226 
    227     def __len__(self):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    223         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    224             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 225                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    226 
    227     def __len__(self):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, return_n_test_samples, return_times, return_estimator, error_score)
    554         fit_time = time.time() - start_time
    555         # _score will return dict if is_multimetric is True
--> 556         test_scores = _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer, is_multimetric)
    557         score_time = time.time() - start_time - fit_time
    558         if return_train_score:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer, is_multimetric)
    597     """
    598     if is_multimetric:
--> 599         return _multimetric_score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
    600     else:
    601         if y_test is None:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in _multimetric_score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorers)
    627             score = scorer(estimator, X_test)
    628         else:
--> 629             score = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)
    630 
    631         if hasattr(score, 'item'):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/scorer.py in __call__(self, estimator, X, y_true, sample_weight)
     95         else:
     96             return self._sign * self._score_func(y_true, y_pred,
---> 97                                                  **self._kwargs)
     98 
     99 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/regression.py in mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight, multioutput)
    239     """
    240     y_type, y_true, y_pred, multioutput = _check_reg_targets(
--> 241         y_true, y_pred, multioutput)
    242     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
    243     output_errors = np.average((y_true - y_pred) ** 2, axis=0,

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/regression.py in _check_reg_targets(y_true, y_pred, multioutput)
     77     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
     78     y_true = check_array(y_true, ensure_2d=False)
---> 79     y_pred = check_array(y_pred, ensure_2d=False)
     80 
     81     if y_true.ndim == 1:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    540         if force_all_finite:
    541             _assert_all_finite(array,
--> 542                                allow_nan=force_all_finite == 'allow-nan')
    543 
    544     if ensure_min_samples > 0:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan)
     54                 not allow_nan and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
     55             type_err = 'infinity' if allow_nan else 'NaN, infinity'
---> 56             raise ValueError(msg_err.format(type_err, X.dtype))
     57     # for object dtype data, we only check for NaNs (GH-13254)
     58     elif X.dtype == np.dtype('object') and not allow_nan:

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').
```